# Moving data across countries securely

Tags: windows, encryption, migration

Currently I am planning on moving data from a number of remote sites across to our head quarters in Germany. The data is too large to replicate/copy over site to site VPN so I'm going to have to do this physically. However I'm struggling to find anything on regulations or the best way to protect the files for the journey. Any advice on what to use in terms on the media and also how to protect the data? I'm guessing all data will be required to be encrypted due to its sensitive nature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Really, this is a non-issue. Copy the data on media of appropriate size, if ncessary encrypted, make a checksum, package it appropriately (depending on the media used, e.g. an optical disc doesn't need ESD shielding), ship it, decrypt and restore it, check with the checksum and you are done. If the checksum fails, rinse and repeat, with better packaging and/or more resilient media.

If your data is subject to special regulations, ask your lawyer.

Comment: Your correct it is a non-issue its a question. All sounds reasonable, if the data is still being written to locally after the shipping do you have advice on what software/method to sync any recent changes across the site to site (I've used beyond compare before) but not on this amount of data (possibly around 1TB).

Comment: This depends on the platform used and the type of data and the nature of the changes (if you have millions of small files and change one of them, you can use other tools as when you have one big file and change 1 byte in it), but we don't do [product recommendations anyway](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Cool thanks it will be a lot of small files, I'll have a look about and see. Guessing site to site speeds, etc will come in to play anyway. Thanks again.